# Error with file reader

Tags: java

I'm getting an error with

```
PersonsInfoData[i] = PersonsInfoin.setPersonsInfo(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4]);
```

> "Incompatible types: void cannot be coverted to PersonsInfo"

```
public void readFile(String fileName)
{
    // Try to read in the data and if an exception occurs go to the Catch section 
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        int i = 0;    // i is used as the line counter
        String line;  // line is used to temporarily store the line read in from the data file

        // Read a line from the data file into the buffer and then check whether
        //      it is null.  The while loop continues until a line read in is null.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Split the line of data (from the text file) and put each entry into the
    //                                             temporary array - temp[]
            String[] temp = line.split(",");
            // Save each entry into its respective PCDataRecord object.
            PersonsInfoData[i] = PersonsInfoin.setPersonsInfo(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4]); 
            i++;  // Increment i so we can keep a count of how many entries have been read in.
        }
        numberOfEntries = i;   // Set numberOfEntries equal to i, to remember how many entries are now in the array 
        br.close();            // Close the BufferedReader
        in.close();            // Close the DataInputStream
        fstream.close();       // Close the FileInputStream
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error Reading File: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a setter statement:

```
PersonsInfoin.setPersonsInfo(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4]);
```

so, not all setters return objects, in your case that method returns returns nothing (`void`) making your statement equivalent to doing:

```
PersonsInfoData[i] = void
```

which is invalid...

Comment: I think you're right about this example, based on the error message, but: (1) a "setter" is a method like any other, so calling it a "setter statement" is not really correct; (2) not all setters return void, and in fact it's fairly common to have setters return the `this` object so that they can be chained.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to write the values to PersonsInfoData[i]. If yes, then replace the line with -

`PersonsInfoData[i].setPersonsInfo(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4]);`